# Annotate a QuerySet with the latest value from a filtered join

Tags: django, join, django-models, annotations

How can I, in a single expression, get the *latest* value from the *filtered* results of a *many-to-one* relationship to *annotate* a Django QuerySet?

Given this toy schema:

```python
from django.db import models

class Lorem(models.Model):
    """ Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet. """

class LoremStatusEvent(models.Model):
    """ A status event change on a given `ipsum` for a `lorem`. """

    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    lorem = models.ForeignKey(Lorem)
    ipsum = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

For the purpose of making a custom QuerySet in a Django `LoremAdmin` (for the `Lorem` model), I need to:

- Derive `foo_status` and `bar_status` each from separate JOIN clauses to a `LoremStatusEvent` model: `lorem.loremstatusevent_set__status`.
- Filter each join to only include those events which are for the corresponding `Ipsum` value: `foo_status_events=LoremStatusEvent.filter(ipsum='foo')`.
- Aggregate the set of status events to only the latest for each corresponding join: `foo_status=LoremStatusEvent.objects.filter(ipsum='foo').latest('created').status`.
- Annotate the results with a couple of extra values, `foo_status` and `bar_status`: `queryset = queryset.annotate(foo_status=???).annotate(bar_status=???)`.

If I invent some functions to do all this – `get_field`, `latest_by`, `filter_by`, `loremstatus_set_of_every_corresponding_lorem` – I could write the admin something like this:

```python
from django.contrib import admin

class LoremAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    """ Django admin for `Lorem` model. """

    class Meta:
        model = Lorem

    def get_queryset(request):
        """ Get the `QuerySet` of all instances available to this admin. """
        queryset = super().get_queryset(request)
        queryset.annotate(
            foo_status=(
                get_field('status')(
                    latest_by('created')(
                        filter_by(ipsum='foo')(
                            loremstatusevent_set_of_every_corresponding_lorem)))),
            bar_status=(
                get_field('status')(
                    latest_by('created')(
                        filter_by(ipsum='bar')(
                            loremstatusevent_set_of_every_corresponding_lorem)))),
        )
        return queryset
```

What actual functions should replace each of these placeholder names?

- `loremstatus_set_of_every_corresponding_lorem`, the equivalent of `Lorem.loremstatusevent_set`.
- `filter_by`, to filter a join at the right side.
- `latest_by`, to aggregate the result set, ordered by a field, to get the single latest instance. I don't see any such [documented aggregation function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#aggregation-functions).
- `get_field`, to reference a field from the resulting instance.

Remember that all this needs to be done on a queryset of `Lorem` instances, accessing the related instances via `Lorem.loremstatusevent_set`; I don't have a `LoremStatusEvent` instance at that point, so I can't directly use attributes of `LoremStatusEvent`.

So, what actual Django functionality should be in the above placeholders?

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31234880/annotate-with-value-of-latest-related-in-django-1-8-using-conditional-annotation

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should be able to do this with the new [Subquery](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions) functionality, which is also available as a [backport to 1.8+](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-subquery).

```
try:
    from django.db.models.expressions import Subquery, OuterRef
except ImportError:
    from django_subquery.expressions import Subquery, OuterRef

class LoremAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # …

    def get_queryset(request):
        queryset = super().get_queryset(request)
        status_event_per_lorem = LoremStatusEvent.objects.filter(
            lorem=OuterRef('pk'))
        latest_status_event_per_lorem = (
            status_event_per_lorem.order_by(
                'pk', '-created').distinct('pk'))
        latest_status_event_for_ipsum_foo = (
            latest_status_event_per_lorem.filter(ipsum='foo'))
        latest_status_event_for_ipsum_bar = (
            latest_status_event_per_lorem.filter(ipsum='bar'))
        queryset = queryset.annotate(
            foo_status=Subquery(
                latest_status_event_for_ipsum_foo.values('status')[:1]), 
            bar_status=Subquery(
                latest_status_event_for_ipsum_bar.values('status')[:1]), 
        )

        return queryset
```

Comment: That raises the error `ValueError: This queryset contains a reference to an outer query and may only be used in a subquery.` I think that's because the `filter(…)` result is then used for `latest(…)`.

Comment: I have found a way to do this which doesn't cause that error; I am editing this answer so it works as intended.

Comment: [Annotation helper to annotate last value of related table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71621283/1731460)

Comment: This solution appends multiple subqueries, see my answer here to get the whole object in just one subquery (Django 3.2+): https://stackoverflow.com/a/73088863/6063532